# How to extract filename from path using beanshell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Getting error message empty 
How to extract filename from path using beanshell
Suppose filepath = /home/user/desktop/file.txt
I want to get file.txt seperately using beanshell in jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [FilenameUtils.getPath() method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getPath(java.lang.String)) like:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

filepath = "/home/user/desktop/file.txt";
filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filepath);

log.info(filename);
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell get filename]

---

Be aware that it is recommended to use [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) instead of Beanshell, Groovy has better performance, it's more Java-compatible and it has some extra language features, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: Thanks one more question how to generate timestamp using beanshell script mmddyyyyhhmmss format not any seperation